# ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, compiling, 22.04

I trying to install python3.8.13 via Pyenv in Ubuntu 22.04, and this appear the error:

```
kev@kev-Modern-15-A5M:~$ pyenv install 3.8.13
Installing Python-3.8.13...
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20220630110509.21390
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20220630110509.21390.log

Last 10 log lines:
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Looking in links: /tmp/tmp_uhv2abg
Processing /tmp/tmp_uhv2abg/setuptools-56.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /tmp/tmp_uhv2abg/pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/home/kev/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-22.0.4 setuptools-56.0.0
```

But I had installed OpenSSL before

```
kev@kev-Modern-15-A5M:~$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1p  21 Jun 2022
built on: Tue Jun 21 13:39:39 2022 UTC
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(char) rc4(8x,int) des(int) idea(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc-5 -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/openssl@1.1"
ENGINESDIR: "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1p/lib/engines-1.1"
```

Comment: What does `libedit-dev` have to do with OpenSSL?

Comment: @muru sorry, i just edited , pls check again, thank you !

Comment: try re-installing OpenSSL with apt.
`sudo apt reinstall openssl`

Comment: @KushagraSrivastava becaue I installed OpenSSL via Hombrew, and is this reason cause the error ? So how to set the path to OpenSSL in Hombrew when I install python via Pyenv ? Thank you !

Comment: Try `brew link --force openssl` then `which openssl` 

Please check if that works.

Comment: @KushagraSrivastava ```ev@kev-Modern-15-A5M:/usr$ brew link --force openssl
Error: No such keg: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openssl
```

Comment: @HuyNguyen https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/install.html 
try checking this. i think installing with homebrew may be the problem. do-
`pip install pyopenssl`.  If pip is not installed- `sudo apt install python-pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give another go at force removing the brewed version of openssl

```
brew uninstall --force openssl
```

Then clean up any older versions and clear the brew cache

```
brew cleanup -s openssl
```

Remove any dead symlinks

```
brew cleanup --prune-prefix
```

Then try reinstalling openssl

```
brew install openssl
```

Comment: don't anything happend, pls check report : https://pastebin.com/WuDirdTA

Comment: `brew uninstall openssl && brew install openssl && CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pyenv install 3.8.13`

Try this. if it doesn't work then I think you should report it on the pyenv github issues page. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues

Comment: don't anything happend https://pastebin.com/38gM6xrx, I think when install python with pyenv, it looking path OpenSSL in system by default, but the OpenSSL is forced in Hombrew, so need to force path to hombrew or uninstall Openssl in Homebrew and resinsall it on system default !

Comment: ```kev@kev-Modern-15-A5M:/$ brew uninstall openssl && brew install openssl && CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pyenv install 3.8.13
Error: No such keg: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openssl
```

Comment: yeah. I was thinking the same thing. pyenv installs python in the system by default but homebrew doesn't. Pyenv was looking for OpenSSL but couldn't find it. On Ubuntu, install with apt. That'll fix it. If you want OpenSSL installed with homebrew then try reporting the issue on pyenv's Github page.

Comment: I uninstalled OpenSSL in Hombrew and try to installed by `sudo apt install openssl`, it ok but when I check the version and path, it still force with Hombrew path https://pastebin.com/J6vKzDdh

Comment: thank you, using Homebrew has many problems, so I do not want to use it, just install packages manually instead of via Hombrew

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, it worked when I run

```shell
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```